# android app does not start intent after login

Tags: java, android

```js
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.zomra">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".Donners"/>
<activity android:name=".ThankYou"/>
<activity android:name=".AddDonner"/>
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

my app does not start new intent activity after login success it just stays in the current activity.and there is another problem if i connect with an emulator it does say login success but with my phone it does not connect to the localhost it says volley error time out, how can i login from my phone to my localhost, thank you.

```js
   
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String txtEmail = email.getText().toString();
                String txtPassword = password.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txtEmail)||TextUtils.isEmpty(txtPassword)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All fields required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    login(txtEmail,txtPassword);
                }
            }
        });

        String loginStatus = sharedPreferences.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.PrefLoginState),"");

        if (loginStatus.equals("loggedin")){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class));
            }

    }
    private void login(final String email, final String password){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Logging in please wait... ");
        progressDialog.show();
        String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/login.php";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), response);
                if (response.equals("Login Success")){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    if (loginState.isChecked()){
                        editor.putString(getResources().getString(R.string.PrefLoginState),"logged in");
                    }
                    else {
                        editor.putString(getResources().getString(R.string.PrefLoginState),"logged out");

                    }
                    editor.apply();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                }
                else {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
                param.put("email",email);
                param.put("password",password);
                return param;
            }
        };
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        MySingleton.getmInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(request);


    }





}
```

Comment: could you add your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: here is my AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app doesn't start because `http://10.0.2.2/login.php` is not accessible from your mobile phone. You need to use `ifconfig` in your terminal and put the IP you're getting from it instead of your variable `URL` and it should do the trick.

Comment: thanks that did the trick for the login success but the activity stays on the same login page,new intent does not work

Comment: which intent is not starting ? the one inside your asynctask ?

Comment: this intent     editor.apply();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
after login success

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416690/how-open-a-new-activity-on-a-onresponse-of-volley could solve your problem